# FFMpeg encoding not working on iPhone 3g but iPhone 4 is working well

Tags: iphone, video, ffmpeg, encode

I'm using the following code to encode video files for mobile devices. The problem is that video (mp4) is playing on iPhone 4 and Android devices well, but not working on iPhone 3g. Any ideas?

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i <source> -vcodec libx264 -b 160k -bf 3 -b_strategy 1 -coder 1 -qmin 7 -qmax 30 -s 640x360 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -me_range 16 -me_method hex -subq 5 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.75 -qdiff 4 -directpred 1 -flags2 +fastpskip -dts_delta_threshold 1 -acodec libfaac -ab 128k <output> -y 2> video_up/log/".$name.".txt > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s too many flags. Try with `-vcodec libx264`, `-vb 1000k`, and `-acodec libfaac` and see if that plays (it should). Then you can try adding the rest to see which causes the problems.

Comment: FFMpeg error message: Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Comment: `ffmpeg -i in.mov -vcodec libx264 -vb 1000k -acodec libfaac out.mov` works for me, FFmpeg 0.7.1 from MacPorts.